# How to increment variable with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

Here's my code:

```
foreach($a as $item):
      echo '<span>'.$item['idx'].'.</span>';
      echo '<a href='.$item['url'].'>'.$item['title'].'</a><br />';
      echo '<span>'.$item['description'].'</span><br /><br />';
endforeach;
```

This is the line I'm specifically having problems with:

```
echo '<span>'.$item['idx'].'.</span>';
```

That line will echo a number from my array, but I need to increment that number by one (1).

I've tried doing this several ways such as adding `+1` or `++1` and I'm not sure if I'm adding it in the wrong place or if I should be using something totally different increment.

What needs to be done to increment that variable by one each time?

Comment: `++` before a variable will increment the variable then return it, `++` after a variable will return it and then increment it. Unsure from your wording which of those is more handy for you.

Comment: Show the code that you tried. It will be easier to help that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo '<span>', $item['idx'] + 1, '</span>';
```

Comment: @ende: read the manual. echo accepts commas for its arguments. It's actually slightly more efficient this way, as php doesn't have to build a new string, print it out, then throw it away.

Comment: thanks, I had a doubt after the edit and I went to check the manual.

Comment: @MarcB Doubt it would matter much, however.

Comment: @WayneWhitty: for a small system, it's essentially noise/rounding errors. for a facebook-sized operation, it'd probably save a few pennies.

Comment: @WayneWhitty In this case it matters quite a lot. With `.`, the result is only `1</span>`.

Answer (score 1):

Just try with:

```
  echo '<span>' . ($item['idx'] + 1) . '.</span>';
```